# Displaying Arrays in innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display two bits of data from an array. The first is the title which is comes under [0][0] and the second is a description which is [0][2].

This is what i have written.

```
element.innerHTML = "<div>" + "<h3>" + all_films[0][0]; + "</h3>" + "<p>" + all_films[0][2]; + "</p>" + "</div>"
```

it's strange because it works if i just write

```
"<div>" + "<p>" + all_films[0][2]; + "</p>" + "</div>"
```

or if i just write

```
"<div>" + "<h3>" + all_films[0][0]; + "</h3>" + "</div>"
```

But they never seem to work together. Why is this? Am i not allowed two arrays in the same thingy or what?

Comment: Well you have a semi-colon in the middle of your statement

Answer (score 2):

You have semicolons where they shouldn’t be, turning your code into this:

```
element.innerHTML = "<div>" + "<h3>" + all_films[0][0];
+"</h3>" + "<p>" + all_films[0][2];
+"</p>" + "</div>";
```

where the last two statements have no effect. (JavaScript has a unary `+` operator, as in `+5 === 5`.) Remove the semicolons:

```
element.innerHTML = "<div>" + "<h3>" + all_films[0][0] + "</h3>" + "<p>" + all_films[0][2] + "</p>" + "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolons:

```
element.innerHTML = "<div>" + "<h3>" + all_films[0][0] + "</h3>" + "<p>" + all_films[0][2] + "</p>" + "</div>";
```

Semis belong at the end of a line of javascript, not in the middle.

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed that closure option before - will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of random semicolons during string concatenation...